# Testcafe won’t run with Yarn 2

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, yarnpkg-v2

Testcafe 1.10 doesn’t seem to run via Yarn 2, while it just works running the globally installed one manually. I get this output:

```
ERROR Error: testcafe-legacy-api tried to access read-file-relative, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: read-file-relative (via "read-file-relative")
Required by: testcafe-legacy-api@npm:4.0.0 (via /data/Fichiers/Code/testcafe/.yarn/cache/testcafe-legacy-api-npm-4.0.0-ff97b69c8c-e4a891ec41.zip/node_modules/testcafe-legacy-api/lib/)
```

I can see that `read-file-relative` *is* listed as a dependency of `testcafe`, but *not* as a dependency of `testcafe-legacy-api` (https://yarnpkg.com/package/testcafe, https://yarnpkg.com/package/testcafe-legacy-api), which itself is a dependency of `testcafe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : PRs on both sides have been merged so it should work now or soon without using the workaround below.**

Apparently `testcafe` and its dependency `testcafe-legacy-api` have several actual dependencies that are not listed in their dependencies listing.

As the [documentation for `.yarnrc.yml`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#packageExtensions) explains:

> Some packages may have been specified incorrectly with regard to their dependencies - for example with one dependency being missing, causing Yarn to refuse it the access. The `packageExtensions` fields offer a way to extend the existing package definitions with additional information.

Adding this to my `.yarnrc.yml` and then running `yarn install` (or `yarn`) fixed it:

```yaml
packageExtensions:
  "testcafe@*":
    dependencies:
      "@babel/runtime": "*"
      "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "*"
  "testcafe-legacy-api@*":
    dependencies:
      "read-file-relative": "*"
      "testcafe-hammerhead": "*"
```

Comment: PRs are in progress to make TestCafe compatible with Yarn 2.
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/5872
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-legacy-api/pull/51
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/2381